# Private variables from arguments list

Tags: javascript

I have the following function declaration:

```
function Linker(linked_class, word_class, colors_count) {
    var _linked_class = linked_class;

    this.say = function() {
        alert(_linked_class);
    }
}
```

I want to use `_linked_class` as a private variable inside the function. My question is whether I need to create `_linked_class` variable inside the function and assign the value of `linked_class` variable passed through arguments list, or I can use the variable passed through arguments as private variable without the declaration? Like the following:

```
function Linker(_linked_class, word_class, colors_count) {
    this.say = function() {
        alert(_linked_class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two popular ways to "do privacy" in JavaScript. One is through closures - the constructor arguments belong to the constructor closure. In that case those variables and functions will be impossible to access from outside of the function.

Another is to treat them as regular variables/methods. An underscore in the beginning isn't a language mechanism but a convention used by programmers to signal privacy. For example:

```
function Linker(linked_class, word_class, colors_count) {
    this.say = function() {
        alert(linked_class);
        // if you want to access a "conventionally private", 
        // (or any other method from the same class), 
        // you can do it like this:
        this._whisper();
    }
    this._whisper = function() {
        alert(linked_class);
    }
    this._pseudoPrivateVariable = 5;
}
```

Underscores are uncommon with closures.

Comment: Thanks! In your example both methods access "linked_class" variable through closure. I understand that an underscore is not a language mechanism. Can you please demonstrate the following "Another is to treat them as regular variables/methods", i.e. how can I access variables without closures?

Comment: Actually my example contains both methods. linked_class is private through closure. _whisper is named like a private method. Everyone can access it, but programmers will know that they normally shouldn't.

Comment: I've added an example of how to call methods from the same class, in case that is what you've meant.

Comment: Sabof, thanks for your comments, but I guess this is still not what I'm asking for. My original question was whether there is any differece between using variable from the arguments list and assigning it to another varible explicitly created inside the function. I also assumed from your answer that there is another way to create and access private variable besides using closure.

Comment: No, there is no difference. All variables declared inside a function, as well as it's arguments belong to the same scope.

Comment: I see, thanks! But do you also suggest that I do not use an underscore for variables accessed through closures even if I treat them as private variable inside the function? Since there is no way to create private variables without closures does it mean that I should not use underscores for varibles at all?

Comment: Variables (or functions) inside closures are always private. I've added an example of a "conventionally private" variable, where an  underscore would be expected.

Comment: Not enough reputation to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

I think Yes, you can do it both ways. Since javascript keeps function context at the time function is created. So in your 2nd example _linked_class will be valid value, whenever "say" is called.

Comment: Thanks! In my both cases I get it working properly, my question is about which one is better and why